# How can I change the size of a UITextField?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uialertcontroller, cgsize

I want to change the size of the UITextField programmatically.

Actually what I want to do exactly is this `UIAlertView` inside I have a `UITextField`. I want to increase the size of this `UITextField`.

Image:

[image]

The code I want is something like this.

`textField.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 250, height: 300)`

But it cannot be used this way.

Comment: UIAlertView was deprecated a long time ago for UIAlertController. But neither supports any UI modifications. It would be better to write your own alert that looks and behaves like you want it to.

Comment: Okey I'll try this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sorry, you can't change the UITextField size directly.

If you want to customize the content of the AlertView like UITextField, you should create a custom UIView and present it modally.

It's same to UIAlertView and UIAlertViewController.